# ¿Cómo puedo añadir más elementos en un ya existente archivo XML de dom4j?

Tags: java, xml, dom4j

Básicamente estoy tratando de añadir más datos a un elemento llamado "Registro" en un archivo ya creado xml de dom4j, pero cada que trato de meterle más datos al elemento del archivo, solo se sustituye.
Ví que `FileWriter` tiene un segundo parámetro que hace que no sobrescriba (`new FileWriter("output.xml", true)`), pero añade de una forma distinta los datos:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Datos>
  <Registro>
    <Producto Nombre="awawa" Descripcion="suii" Material="el" Stock="3" Quilates="5" Volumen="7" Precio="3"/>
  </Registro>
  <Historial/>
</Datos>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Datos>
  <Registro>
    <Producto Nombre="asd" Descripcion="gfd" Material="1" Stock="2" Quilates="3" Volumen="4" Precio="5"/>
  </Registro>
  <Historial/>
</Datos>
```

Se crean dos elementos bases "Datos", y yo quiero que en vez de que se hagan dos o más elementos base "Datos", se le agreguen más datos en "Registro" del primer elemento base "Datos".

Este es mi código:

```
static void OpcNewProduct(){
    var In = new Scanner(System.in);
    try(FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter("output.xml", true)){
        Document document = DocumentHelper.createDocument();
        
        Element Datos = document.addElement("Datos");
        
        Element Registro = Datos.addElement("Registro");
        Element Historial = Datos.addElement("Historial");

        Element Producto = Registro.addElement("Producto");
        System.out.println("Si desea cancelar, ponga '/leave'\nen cualquier momento\n");
        for(Map<String, String> Atributo : Propertys.values()){
            String Propiedad;
            do{
                System.out.println("Ingrese "+Atributo.get("Propiedad"));
                Propiedad = In.nextLine();
                if(Propiedad.equalsIgnoreCase("/leave")) return;
                System.out.println(!Propiedad.matches(Atributo.get("Regex")) ? "Caracteres incorrectos" : "");
            }while(!Propiedad.matches(Atributo.get("Regex")));
            Producto.addAttribute(Atributo.get("Propiedad"), Propiedad);
        }
        XMLWriter writer = new XMLWriter(fileWriter, OutputFormat.createPrettyPrint());
        writer.write( document );
        writer.close();
        
    }catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usa un [`Transformer`](https://dom4j.github.io/#xslt) para modificar tu archivo original (source) en un nuevo archivo con nuevos nodos (result). Te adjunto un ejemplo que funciona con tu archivo.

```java
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.OutputKeys;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import java.io.IOException;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws TransformerException, ParserConfigurationException, IOException, SAXException {
        DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document document = documentBuilder.parse("output.xml");
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(document);

        Element root = document.getDocumentElement();
        Node registro = root.getElementsByTagName("Registro").item(0);

        Element producto = document.createElement("Producto");
        producto.setAttribute("Descripcion", "maxsdd");
        producto.setAttribute("Material", "ella");
        producto.setAttribute("Precio", "5");
        producto.setAttribute("Quilates", "59");
        producto.setAttribute("Stock", "11");
        producto.setAttribute("Volumen", "12");

        registro.appendChild(producto);

        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        transformerFactory.setAttribute("indent-number", 1);
        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult("output.xml");
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
        transformer.transform(source, result);
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Cuáles son la librerías? las perdí porque ya no me deja retroceder los cambios en java

Comment: Por cierto, me da error en  Document = documentBuilder.parse("output.xml");

Comment: @DGNutria la librería es la misma que pones en tu pregunta `dom4j`. Puedes [descargarla acá](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.dom4j/dom4j/2.1.3). Te agregué los `imports` para que no tuvieras errores. Muy buena suerte.